# Automation of export data

Tags: cognito-forms

I know about the option to export data to Excel manually.

Is there a way to export Cognito Forms to Excel (for example) automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can have data sent to Google Sheets each time a new entry is submitted. This can be done by using [Zapier](https://zapier.com). Cognito Forms can be connected to Google Sheets and the data for each entry can be sent to the sheet to update as each new entry is submitted.

We do have a [blog post](http://blog.cognitoforms.com/keep-your-form-data-in-sync-with-google-sheets) about setting up the connection between Google Sheets and Cognito Forms.